# Get the difference between two dates when string value changes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to get the number of days between the change of string values (ie., the `symbol` column) in one column, grouped by their respective `id`. I want a separate column for `datediff` like the one below.

```
id  date         symbol  datediff
1   2022-08-26   a       0
1   2022-08-27   a       0
1   2022-08-28   a       0
2   2022-08-26   a       0
2   2022-08-27   a       0
2   2022-08-28   a       0
2   2022-08-29   b       3
3   2022-08-29   c       0
3   2022-08-30   b       1
```

For `id = 1`, `datediff = 0` since `symbol` stayed as `a`. For `id = 2`, `datediff = 3` since `symbol` changed after 3 days from `a` to `b`. Hence, what I'm looking for is a code that computes the difference in which the id changes it's symbol.

I am currently using this code:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

diff = ['0 days 00:00:00']

for st,i in zip(df['symbol'],df.index):
    if i > 0:#cannot evaluate previous from index 0
        if df['symbol'][i] != df['symbol'][i-1]:
            diff.append(df['date'][i] - df['data_ts'][i-1])
        else:   
            diff.append('0 days 00:00:00')
```

The output becomes:

```
id  date         symbol  datediff
1   2022-08-26   a       0
1   2022-08-27   a       0
1   2022-08-28   a       0
2   2022-08-26   a       0
2   2022-08-27   a       0
2   2022-08-28   a       0
2   2022-08-29   b       1
3   2022-08-29   c       0
3   2022-08-30   b       1
```

It also computes the difference between two different ids. But I want the computation to be separate from different ids.

I only see questions about difference of dates when values changes, but not when string changes. Thank you!

Comment: How exactly is the datediff being calculated? Like how is datediff 3 for id 2, symbol a?

Comment: i'm sorry it's a typo in the date. it should be 2022-08-30 instead of 2022-08-28

Comment: The logic about how `datediff` is computed is not clear from given explanation and example. You may want to provide more details for better understanding.

Comment: i changed it now. thank you for your suggestion. what im looking for is a code to calculate how much days elapsed for the symbol to change in each id

Comment: Does a series of symbols within one id always end with a single different symbol? Or is it possible to get `aaabac` for example?

Comment: it's always a single symbol only. it's actually a set of string but i assigned a single symbol for each of them for easier computation.

Comment: @Jel does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC: my solution works with the assumption that the symbols within one id ends with a single changing symbol, if there is any (as in the example given in the question).

First use `df.groupby` on `id` and `symbol` and get the minimum date for each combination. Then, find the difference between the dates within each `id`. This gives the `datediff`. Finally, merge the findings with the original dataframe.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['id', 'symbol'], sort=False).agg({'date': np.min}).reset_index()

df1['datediff'] = abs(df1.groupby('id')['date'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0))
df1 = df1.drop(columns='date')

df_merge = pd.merge(df, df1, on=['id', 'symbol'])
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is it possible to include time in computation in ```date```?  So the format of diff will be ```D days HH:MM:SS```?

Comment: Yes! Just replace my second line of code with: `df1['datediff'] = df1.groupby('id')['date'].diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))`